# Does .update() also cancels .transaction() as .set() does?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In my Cloud Function, I want to override some values of my Realtime Database. I could use multiple set(), but an update() would be just one call. There is another function that uses transaction() that update one of those fields conditionally (if its value is X it will be changed to Y).

There is a note on the docs:

> Note: Modifying data with set() will cancel any pending transactions
> at that location, so extreme care should be taken if mixing set() and
> transaction() to update the same data.

(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#transaction)

My question is: does an update() have the same behavior of set() at this specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're updating data that is part of the transaction, it doesn't matter what write mechanism you use. So `update()` and `set()` will have the same result here.